# RP - Posting formdata not passing correctly to service

Tags: node.js, rest, post, request, request-promise

I need to pass file with formdata and server written in java should receive as below

public Response uploadFileWithMetadata(ObjectMetadata objectMetadata, MultipartBody multipartBody) {}

below is the client code and I am passing which is sending as objectMetadata as null and multipartBody array has 2 values, one with file and other with objectMetadata and that is not accepted by service as valid input. ObjectMetadata received on the server side should be **application/json and I set that in the formdata. But that is received as text/plain and I am suspecting, that is causing issue**

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
           uri: url,
           formData: {
               objectMetadata: {value: JSON.stringify(inputToPass),options:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}},
               file1: fs.createReadStream('/Users/mohansee/Desktop/Node_drekar_setup.docx')
           }
       };

rp(options) 
    .then(function (body) { 
        console.log('inside success'); console.log(body) 
    }) .catch(function (err) { 
    console.log('inside error'); 
    console.log(err); 
});
```

Please check and let know if I am missing something in the data section that need to be passed as separate parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the formData and adding header solved the problem

```
        formData: {
            objectMetadata: {
                value: inputToPass,
                options: {              
                    contentType: 'application/json'             
                }
            },
            file1: { 
                value: fs.createReadStream('Node_drekar_setup.docx'),             
                options: {                
                    contentType: 'multipart/form-data'             
                }
            }
        }
```